# How to retrieve information about applied SFSoupIndex by using the mobile SDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I'm looking for an API (or native mobile SDK) call to retrieve information about applied `SFSoupIndex` aka `kSoupIndexTypeString` for all / specified soup.

The General behind this is to create local classes that represents soups from the remote.

I thought that such information are included in metadata api json output but I was not able to find them.

Thanks for any helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible solution**

Use the Metadata API to retrieve the `searchable` property to identify the index attributes.

This may be a little bit dirty to understand the `Index` as index possible full text search value.